# save jsp file in excel with browse option

Tags: jsp

I want to save output of the jsp file in excel.
I have tried the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Save File</title>
</head>
<body>
<%@ page import="org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet"%>
<%@ page import="org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook"%>
<%@ page import="org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell"%>
<%@ page import="org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow"%>
<%@ page import="org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCellStyle"%>
<%@ page import="org.apache.poi.hssf.util.HSSFColor"%>
<%@ page import="java.io.* " %>
<%@page import="java.sql.* "%>
 <%
// String EX_DT=null;
 String filenm=request.getParameter("filenm");

 File file=new File("c:\\"+filenm+".xls");

 boolean exists = file.exists();

 if (exists)
 {
  out.println("File or Directory exist.PLZ enter another filename");
 }
 else
 {
 String s1=null;

   try
 {
     //  EX_DT=(String)session.getAttribute( "dte" );
     // out.println("Ex_Dt in try"+EX_DT);
   HSSFWorkbook hwb=new HSSFWorkbook();
   HSSFSheet sheet =  hwb.createSheet("new sheet");
   HSSFSheet sheet1 =  hwb.createSheet("new sheet1");
    HSSFRow rowhead=   sheet.createRow((short)0);
    //rowhead.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue("MKT");
   rowhead.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue("SECURITY");
   rowhead.createCell((short) 1).setCellValue("PREV_CL_PR");
   rowhead.createCell((short) 2).setCellValue("CLOSE_PRIC");
  rowhead.createCell((short) 3).setCellValue("NET_TRDQTY");
  rowhead.createCell((short) 4).setCellValue("NET_TRDVAL");



   Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
   String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://";
   Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"sa","SQL1423#3"); 
   Statement st=con.createStatement();
   ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("Select * from TtOne ");
   int i=1;
   while(rs.next())
   {

   HSSFRow row=   sheet.createRow((short)i);
    //s1=rs.getString("EX_DT");
  //    out.println("s1"+s1);
  // if(s1.equals((String)session.getAttribute( "dte" )))
   //{

 //     out.println("EX_DT in if of while");

   row.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue(rs.getString("SECURITY"));
   row.createCell((short) 1).setCellValue(rs.getString("PREV_CL_PR"));
   row.createCell((short) 2).setCellValue(rs.getString("CLOSE_PRIC"));
   row.createCell((short) 3).setCellValue(rs.getString("NET_TRDQTY"));
   row.createCell((short) 4).setCellValue(rs.getString("NET_TRDVAL"));

   i++;
  // }
   }



   FileOutputStream fileOut =  new FileOutputStream(file);//file

   hwb.write(fileOut);

   fileOut.close();

   %><h1><b><i><% out.println("Your excel file has been generated!");%>

    </i></b></h1>



    <% 


 }

  catch ( Exception ex )
   {   
    System.out.println(ex);
    } 

 }

  %>
</body>
</html>
```

But instead of hard coded path, I want user to specify the path. And file should be saved at that location. So I want a dialogue box where browse option is available, and after selecting the path and clicking on save the output should be stored in excel file.

Comment: Should the file be saved in the machine where the webserver runs or in the machine where the webbrowser runs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you intend to let the user download this file, you should not be storing the file in webserver's local disk file system. You should instead be sending this file to the HTTP response.

You first need to turn your JSP into a [servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info), otherwise the excel file will be corrupted with JSP's own HTML and template content, because the JSP itself is part of the HTTP response.

Put all that Java (no HTML! no `out.println()` statements!) code in the `doGet()` or `doPost()` method of the servlet, depending on the request type. Then, all you need to do is to replace the following single line in your original Java code

```
hwb.write(fileOut);
```

by the following lines

```
response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + filenm + "\"");
hwb.write(response.getOutputStream());
```

The first one tells the browser what kind of file it is, so that it can if necessary associate the default application (MS Excel) with it. The second one tells that the browser should pop a *Save As* dialog. The third one tells POI that it should write the Excel file to the HTTP response.

Don't forget to *remove* that `new File()` nonsense. It would only save the file on the machine where the webserver runs. You need to realize that in live production environments the webserver runs at a physically different machine than the webbrowser.

On an unrelated note, your JDBC code is leaking resources. You forgot to `close()` the `Connection`, `Statement` and `ResultSet` in the `finally` of the `try` block. This will lead the DB to run out of them on long term. Fix that accordingly as well.

Comment: And as I have made lot of changes to my original code,I forgot to close the Connection, Statement and Resultset here. Thanks for pointing out my mistake.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This code is working. But the problem is now it is displaying only first value in the excel sheet. I have placed the code in while(rs.next()) but still it is showing only first value in excel sheet.

Comment: Hey the problem is solved now. Actually I was trying a code in while loop, after making some changes in my code, it worked. So the above code is working.